# cannot get post values send with ajaxcall

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

My problem is the folowing:
I am trying to retrieve the postvalue, but whenever I put that statement in the php code the ajaxcall will fail.

I cannot see what I am missing here??

```
$.ajax({
            url: "includes/livetabs.php?actie=sessiegebruikersnaam", 
            data: {gebruikersnaam: tbgebruikersnaam},
            cache: false,
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(data) {
            //opslaan van gebruikersnaam in php sessie
        /*$.post("includes/livetabs.php", {"sessiegebruikersnaam": chatnaam},
                 function(data){*/
                    //doe nog iets
                aa= data.status;
                bb=data.naam;
            //krijg de instellingen terug
            alert(aa);
            alert(bb);  
        }});

//php section
if(isset($_GET['actie'])){
**$n=$_POST['gebruikersnaam'];**
    if ($_GET['actie']=="sessiegebruikersnaam"){
    if (!isset($_SESSION['username'])){
    $_SESSION['username'] = $n ;}
    header('Content-type: application/json');
    //geef ook meteen de secondary instellingen terug

    ?>

{
        "status": "somevalue",
        "naam": "anothervalue"
}
    <?php
    exit(0); // Stop het script.
    }
}
```

thanks, Richard

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: The stuff you are passing to the server should be wrapped in parenthesis, also, I would specify the type of request for clarity:

```
data: ({gebruikersnaam : tbgebruikersnaam}),
type: "POST", //just in case
```

Badly formed json will not work with $.ajax. Try using [json_encode](http://www.php.net/json_encode) on the server to generate the json:

```
//php section
if(isset($_GET['actie'])){
**$n=$_POST['gebruikersnaam'];**
    if ($_GET['actie']=="sessiegebruikersnaam"){
    if (!isset($_SESSION['username'])){
    $_SESSION['username'] = $n ;}
    header('Content-type: application/json');
    //geef ook meteen de secondary instellingen terug
    echo json_encode(array('status' => 'someValue', 'naam' => 'anotherValue'));
    exit();
    ?>
```

Also, it might be clearer to use [$.getJSON](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/jQuery.getJSON) instead of $.ajax.

Comment: You would also want to make sure nothing else is being output to the client before that final echo.

Comment: but I don't output anything other then those two testvalues and they work. It's just when I ask for the postvalue it is not working.

Comment: great, thank you. Your last edit did the trick. I was either one or both of those that made it work.

Comment: @Richard If this answer solved your problem you might consider accepting it.